# The proper way to erase states of multiple slices in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have a React app and I'm using **Redux Toolkit**.
I have multiple slices created for different app's components.
Here is the example of one of them:

```
const invitationsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
    selectId: (invitation) => invitation.guid
});

const initialState = invitationsAdapter.getInitialState({
    invitationsLoading: 'idle'
});

export const invitationsList = createAsyncThunk(
    'invitation/invitationsList',
    (payload, { getState }) => {
        const { getEmploymentInvitationsList } = useTenderAPI();
        const { userAccessToken } = getState().user;
        return getEmploymentInvitationsList(payload, userAccessToken);
    }
)

const invitationsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'invitation',
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            //getEmploymentInvitationsList
            .addCase(invitationsList.pending, (state) => { state.invitationsLoading = 'loading' })
            .addCase(invitationsList.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log('invitations list ', action.payload)
                state.invitationsLoading = 'idle';
                invitationsAdapter.setMany(state, action.payload);
            })
            .addCase(invitationsList.rejected, (state) => { state.invitationsLoading = 'error' })
    }
});

const { reducer } = invitationsSlice;
export const { selectAll } = invitationsAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.invitations);

export default reducer;
```

What I try to achieve is to **erase all data stored in the Redux store for all slices on User logout event at same time**.

I searched through Google and found some way with use of a `combinereducers`. It looks like this.

**Store component**:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import user from '../components/userLogin/userSlice'
import order from '../components/orders/orderSlice'
import employment from "../components/employment/employmentSlice";
import invitations from "../components/employment/invitationsSlice";

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
    user,
    order,
    employment,
    invitations
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'user/userLoggingOut') {
        return combinedReducer(undefined, action);
    }
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
};

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})

export default store
```

Handling the user logout event:

```
    const handleLogOut = () => {
        dispatch(userLoggingOut());
    }
```

The reducer for user logout action is empty so the `rootreducer` takes the action for it:

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: filledInitialState,
    reducers: {
        userLoggingOut: (state) => {
        },
    },
```

After these changes strange behavior occurs. After I trigger logout of an user some of states in slices are cleared out but not all of them and not the same ones as before. For example when I press logout button in app the user slice can be erased but on the next iteration it will be not, so it looks completely random for me.
Maybe there are some mistakes in the code above or maybe this thing should not work such way at all.

P.S. by erase of state I mean clearing enteties array of slices

P.P.S. I can create a userLoggingOut action in every slice and will be able to successfully clear all enteties but that means I should dispatch action of every slice in my handleLogOut function and it's a lot of code and doesn't seem for me as an optimized way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this [`extraReducer`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers) to all of your slice reducers and set the value of each slice reducer to `initialState`.

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
 builder
  .addCase('LOGOUT', (state) => {
     Object.assign(state, initialState);
  })
}
```

Now, whenever user click Log out, simply do:

```
 const handleLogOut = () => {
   dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT'});
 }
```

It will set all slice reducers to their `initialState`. So, you do not need to dispatch action of every slice reducer in your `handleLogOut` method.